# autosize window to fit datagradview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible in vb.net to autosize the form window to change it width to the datagridview width?

I have kept looking for a while now but can only find on how to resize the datagridview itself.

This is code for prepare Datagridview

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
   Dim rowvalue As String Dim cellvalue(20) As String 
   Dim streamReader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("test.csv") 

   While streamReader.Peek() <> -1 
     rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine() 
     cellvalue = rowvalue.Split(","c) 
     DataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellValue) 
   End While 

   streamReader.Close() 
 End Sub
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the main form containing the gridview?

```
Me.Height = heightVal
Me.Width = widthVal
```

Depending upon the variation in the size of the gridview, you can use the two properties above to adapt the size of the main form. Bear in mind that this will provoke the location of the form to be changed and thus you should also have to affect it at runtime (`Me.Left` & `Me.Top`).

If it is not the main form, you should replace `Me`, with the given object (e.g., `Panel1`).

----------------- EXAMPLE

```
    Dim rightGap As Double = 10
    Dim bottomGap As Double = 10
    If (DataGridView1.Location.X + DataGridView1.Width > Me.Width + rightGap) Then
        Me.Width = 2 * Me.Width - (DataGridView1.Location.X + DataGridView1.Width) + rightGap
    End If
    If (DataGridView1.Location.Y + DataGridView1.Height > Me.Height + bottomGap) Then
        Me.Height = 2 * Me.Height - (DataGridView1.Location.Y + DataGridView1.Height) + bottomGap
    End If
```

I am also including "gaps" both at the right and at the bottom of the form. This code (or something on these lines) should be enough to make sure that the Height/Width values are updated at runtime without any problem (gridview always properly located inside the form). 
Lastly, you should bear in mind that the size of the datagridview does not have to match the one of columns/rows. In order to avoid wrong resizing, you would have also to make sure that the total width of all the rows matches the width of datagridview and the total height of all the columns its height

---

Comment: Yes, but: Me.Width = DataGridView1.Width doesn't change the forms width to fit match the same size as the datagridview, if it makes any difference the headers are hard coded into the form and the data is populated from a csv file.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. You have to create an algorithm to account for the variations of the datagridview1 on account of the increases/decreases. Take as a reference the initial values and initial positions of the datagridview. Bear in mind that the datagridview is, most likely, not located in 0,0 and thus this should be accounted for. Example: width of datagridview = 10 and its left = 5; the minimum width of the form should be 15.

Comment: `Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim rowvalue As String
        Dim cellvalue(20) As String
        Dim streamReader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("test.csv")
        While streamReader.Peek() <> -1
            rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine()
            cellvalue = rowvalue.Split(","c)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellValue)
        End While
        streamReader.Close()
    End Sub `

Comment: Let me write a small code for you to explain the ideas. Give me some minutes (I am doing something else right now).

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of the kind of approach I would take to account for your situation.